# jQuery trigger not working as hoped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this

```
$('input[type=radio][name="voucher_type"]').live('change', function() {
//stuff here
});
```

So when a radio button is clicked, things happen. The radio button is within a div which is styled as a big button with a background image, etc.

The problem is, users will click the image, and expect it to click the button. I can't use label, which I know will check the radio, so I've tried this code below:

```
    $('div.voucher_box').click(function(){
    $(this).children('input').attr("checked", "checked");
    $(this).closest("input").trigger('click');
});
```

I hoped when the div class voucher_box is clicked, it'd trigger a click/change event on the radio button and fire all the code that runs when the radios are changed.

Can anyone see what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Would'nt it be better to trigger the change event, as that is what is bound?

Comment: Can you post a link or put your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have bound `change` event, then you have to trigger `change` event but not `click`:

```
$('div.voucher_box').click(function() {
    $(this).children(":radio").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
}
```

Pay attention that starting from jQuery version 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. You should use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Comment: Hi, it looks good, but I get an error saying "prop()" isn't a method. We're using quite an old jquery. 1.4.4. Is that why?

Comment: Then use `attr("checked", "checked")` instead.

Comment: I knew that! Thanks. Great help.